# retrieve and combine chunks of information from string using regex in postgres

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I need to retrieve information from structured text fragments which have the following format:

`(AAB) Some name1 here 1234 (BB) More 12-text 99 (XY*) Hello world 12`

What I want to get out is the following: `{AAB1234, BB99, XY*12}`

**Strategy**:

1. get characters inside brackets [e.g. (`XY*`)]
2. get last group of digits which is either followed by brackets or the end of string [e.g. `1234` (]

I did not get very far, as my regex skills are fairly limited.

```
SELECT regexp_matches('(AAB) Some name1 1234 (BB) More text 99 (XY*) Hello world 12',
          '\((.*?)\).*?(\d+)', 'g');
```

Giving

```
{AAB,1}
{BB,9}
{XY*,1}
```

Any ideas?

**Add-on question**:

I have the above text information in a column `information` in table `my_table` and I want to write the results into column `results`. How can I integrate the above solution into an `UPDATE` statement?
I.e.

```
UPDATE my_table SET results = ???.
```

Comment: Do you want to get an actual single string, or an array?

Comment: I am okay with both. Actually, I am still a bit unsure what would be the best way to store it.

Comment: There's no absolute "best way", it depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
SELECT array_agg(v) FROM (
    SELECT array_to_string(
               regexp_matches(
                   '(AAB) Some name1 1234 (BB) More text 99 (XY*) Hello world 12',
                   '\((.*?)\).*?(\d+)(?=$| \()', 'g'
               ),
               ''
           ) as v
    ) s;
```

Note that as usual, regexps can be quite fragile if you don't have a very formal definition of the syntax.

#### EDIT

To update, this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE my_table SET results = ARRAY(
    SELECT array_to_string(
               regexp_matches(
                   information,
                   '\((.*?)\).*?(\d+)(?=$| \()', 'g'
               ),
               ''
           )
    );
```

It expects results to be of type `text[]`. Alternatively, you could store the results as a string by adding an `array_to_string`.

Comment: Great, thanks. One additional question (see edit): How can I use this in an UPDATE statement? I fail to get this right. TIA